# Can't import store redux out of files that are not part of the component tree? "cannot access store before initialization"

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Yesterday I was getting a problem trying to access the store. It said that it is not possible to access the store before initialization, but the file that use and import the store is only called in a component, which is part of the component tree and consequently only rendered after the app containing the store.

So, after realizing a few things, the conclusion I came to was: Unable to import the store into files that are not part of the component tree. In my case, I imported this to create an axios instance, which obtained the state of the store, and was used to make api calls on a component that is part of the app.

I am correct to say that it is not possible to import store in files that are not component files, i.e, that not part of the main app tree?

for example:

step 1: i have store initialized in "store/index":

```
const store = configureStore(//...)
export default store;
```

step 2: i import the store in the "app/index":

```
import store, { history } from "store";
const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <AppRouter history={history} />
  </Provider>
);
```

step 3: i import the store in the "http/private" to get state and dispatch in a axios instance:

```
import store from store;
const {access, token} = store.getState().login.token; // store returns undefined when the componente call this
```

step 4: i import the "http/private" that contains store import, in my "componentes/haderNav/index", that are part of the app three:

```
import apiPrivate from "http/private"
// ...
const userData = await apiPrivate.getUserData() 
// ...
```

source code of my app that raise this error: https://gitlab.com/marcosroot/webstation.dev-client

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking--"files that are not part of component files" doesn't make sense to me. Can you re-word to make things more clear?

Comment: Would you mind providing an example? [Please see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)